# str_replace() does not work for some characters

Tags: php, str-replace

For exemple, if I use a function like:

```
function string_cleaner($string) {
    $replace = array('Ø', 'ø', 'ă', 'ü'); // more and more special chars
    $replacement = array('', '', 'a', 'u');

    $string = str_replace($replace, $replacement, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

This does not work when I call, and use these special characters. With other simple characters I don't have problems...

The strings are UTF-8 encrypted. What would be the cause?

Comment: Is your php file stored in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Most likely if strings are UTF8, then the source file, in which these characters are hardcoded, isn't in UTF8.

Comment: If they are UTF-8 encoded you need to replace the encoded version, you are saying replace the unencoded one, which it shouldn't find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and make sure that your source files are encoded in UTF-8 as well. This can be easily avoided in the future by changing the default encoding to UTF-8 within your text editor of choice.